# Lua string.gsub() by '%s' or '\n' pattern

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

English isn't my mother tongue,so it's a little hard to describe the question.
I wanna to get 'd=40' in str by lua string.gsub(),but there's some problem.

> ------code below---
>   local str =
>   [==[
>   -- a=10
>   - -b=20
>    --c=30
>   d=40
>   ]==]
>
> local pat1 = [=[%s[%s]]=]
>   local pat2 = [=[\n[%s]]=]
>   str:gsub(pat1, function(s) print("pat1>>" .. s) end)   --pat1>>d=40
>   str:gsub(pat2, function(s) print("pat2<<" .. s) end)   --not match
>
> local re1,_ = str:gsub("\n","$")
>   local re2,_ = str:gsub("%s","$")
>   print(re1)  --a=10$- -b=20$       --c=30$d=40$
>   print(re2)  --$a=10$-$-b=20$$     --c=30$d=40$

As Lua 5.1 Reference Manual Say
%s: represents all space characters.
I Think it equal to '\n',' 'and'\t'.

Question : Why pat2 can't match?
But I think pat2 is right,there's a '\n'befor'd=40' ,
so I think It can match ,but it can't work,why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `[[]]` notation for strings, that's a special string literal that takes the string exactly as you provide it. No character escaping is done. You can put some number of `=` characters in the brackets, to make it a bit easier to let you use [ characters in the string.

The string literal `"\n"` is one character, representing the newline. That's because of the use of the escape character `\`. The escape character applied to the 'n' character means "the newline character."

The string literal `[[\n]]` is exactly what it says: the character '\' followed by the character 'n'. Because no escaping is done, `\n` is not treated specially. It's exactly what it looks like.

Therefore, when you say `local pat2 = [=[\n[%s]]=]` You're saying "the first character should be '\' followed by 'n' followed by a space. That's not what you want; you *want* the escaping to work. So you should use a regular string literal: `local pat2 = "\n[%s]"`.